# How to retrieve data with filter by Particular date using REST API call in Sharepoint list 2013.?

Tags: angularjs, rest, date, sharepoint-2013, office365api

I have created date field in my sharepoint list. And I have to retrieve data from sharepoint list by filter with created date. I have tried some rest api calls but I didn't get correct way of filter by date.

Trying codes are:

```
var CurrentDate = $("datepickerID").val();
CurrentDate = new Date(CurrentDate);
CurrentDate = CurrentDate.toISOString();
"/_api/lists/listname/items?$filter=Created ge 'CurrentDate'"
"/_api/lists/listname/items?$filter=Created eq 'CurrentDate'"
"/_api/lists/listname/items?$filter=Created eq datetime'CurrentDate'"
```

I need data of created date equal to `CurrentDate` records. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 2):

To filter between two date ranges, you could try to use query like:

```
"/_api/Web/lists/listname/Items?$filter= (Created  ge datetime'2016-04-27T00:00:00.000Z') and (Created  lt datetime'2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z')"
```

Your requirement is to filter the list items in "current day" from date picker . So you could try to modify your code as :

```
var CurrentDate = $("datepickerID").val();
CurrentDate = new Date(CurrentDate);
startDay=CurrentDate.toISOString();
// add a day
CurrentDate.setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() + 1);
endDay=CurrentDate.toISOString();

"/_api/Web/lists/listname/Items?$filter= (Created  ge datetime'"+startDay+"') and (Created  lt datetime'"+endDay+"')"
```

Comment: Thanks  @Nan Yu , your code very smart. But i am getting problem in CurrentDate convert to ISOString format. Because toISOString() method return date with time . if ISOString of Date not have time or its zero then only filter concept worked. If not zero filter not worked. That is my problem.

forExample,

>>bb = new Date()
Thu Apr 28 2016 18:40:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
>>bb.toISOString()
"2016-04-28T13:10:16.338Z"

 How can i replace the ISOStringDate of time value?

Comment: take a look at moment.js, save you time on this "DATE" conversion